# Slider JQuery UI - Suavizar movimiento

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, slider

He incluido el siguiente `slider`, pero no encuentro las opciones para que no se mueva con los `steps`, es decir, de un punto a otro de forma brusca al no haber muchos valores, sino que lo pueda mover de forma suave.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43tpdr6L/

```js
var initialValue = 4;
var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {
  var curValue = ui.value || initialValue;
  var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip-slider"><div class="tooltip-inner"><span>' + curValue + '</span><span class="last">años</span></div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';

  $('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);

}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#gs1").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 3,
    max: 8,
    value: initialValue,
    create: sliderTooltip,
    slide: sliderTooltip,
    animate: true
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.slider .plazo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Heavy';
  color: #007BC6;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.tooltip-slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1020;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  visibility: visible;
  margin-top: -2px;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.tooltip-slider .tooltip-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0%, 30%);
  transform-origin: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #4A4A4A;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.tooltip-inner span {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Medium';
  font-size: 20px;
}

.tooltip-inner span.last {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.slider-anyos {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-anyos .anyos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Medium';
}

.slider-anyos .anyos.last {
  left: inherit;
  right: 0;
}

.ui-slider {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 560px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
  background: #ED6B51;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a79f;
  border-right: 1px solid #a8a79f;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ui-slider-range {
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.ui-slider-range-min {
  background-color: #007BC6;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
  background: #007BC6 !important;
  border: 5px solid #fff !important;
  border-radius: 100px !important;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  height: 20px !important;
  width: 20px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  top: -7px !important;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="slider">
  <div class="plazo">Plazo</div>
  <div class="slider-anyos">
    <div class="slider" id="gs1"></div>
    <div class="anyos first">3</div>
    <div class="anyos last">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

He probado también con la opción `steps: 0` pero no consigo.

¿Alguna idea que pueda aplicar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una cosa que podrías hacer es poner el `step` a un valor pequeño como .1 o .01, de ese modo la animación será más fluida (mientras menor sea el número más pasos habrá y más fluido se verá).

Entonces el problema es que el valor ya no es un número entero sino que tendrá decimales y eso no es lo que quieres que se muestre en el *tooltip* cuando se mueve el slider. Lo que harías entonces es que redondearías el valor (en mi ejemplo he redondeado hacia abajo usando <s>`floor`</s> `round`, pero podrías redondear usando <s>`round`</s> `floor` o `ceil`, el que mejor que venga).

> Inicialmente usaba `floor`, pero entonces era dificil seleccionar el número 8. Usando `round` es más fácil seleccionar los valores de los extremos

Por último deberías crear un controlador del evento `stop` que hará que cuando se suelte el slider sí que salte al valor correspondiente (haciendo algo parecido al redondeo de arriba y asignando el nuevo valor con "value").

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
var initialValue = 4;
var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {
  var curValue = Math.round(ui.value || initialValue);
  var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip-slider"><div class="tooltip-inner"><span>' + curValue + '</span><span class="last">años</span></div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';

  $('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);

}

var stopTooltip = function(event, ui) {
  var curValue = Math.round(ui.value || initialValue);
  $("#gs1").slider("value", curValue);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#gs1").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 3,
    max: 8,
    value: initialValue,
    create: sliderTooltip,
    slide: sliderTooltip,
    stop: stopTooltip,
    animate: true,
    step:0.01
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.slider .plazo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Heavy';
  color: #007BC6;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.tooltip-slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1020;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  visibility: visible;
  margin-top: -2px;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.tooltip-slider .tooltip-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0%, 30%);
  transform-origin: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #4A4A4A;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.tooltip-inner span {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Medium';
  font-size: 20px;
}

.tooltip-inner span.last {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.slider-anyos {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-anyos .anyos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Medium';
}

.slider-anyos .anyos.last {
  left: inherit;
  right: 0;
}

.ui-slider {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 560px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
  background: #ED6B51;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a79f;
  border-right: 1px solid #a8a79f;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ui-slider-range {
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.ui-slider-range-min {
  background-color: #007BC6;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
  background: #007BC6 !important;
  border: 5px solid #fff !important;
  border-radius: 100px !important;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  height: 20px !important;
  width: 20px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  top: -7px !important;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="slider">
  <div class="plazo">Plazo</div>
  <div class="slider-anyos">
    <div class="slider" id="gs1"></div>
    <div class="anyos first">3</div>
    <div class="anyos last">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Esto es lo que estaba buscando, y pensaba que tenía que hacer algo así, solo que no caí en la cuenta de poner un `step` con valores decimales (ya que uso enteros).

Answer (score 3):

Una idea rápida: Pon 10x veces mas valores, en tu caso, del 30 al 80 y luego en todos los usos lo divides por 10 y le haces un floor.

[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/43tpdr6L/1/):

```js
var initialValue = 4;
var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {
  var curValue = ui.value || initialValue;
  var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip-slider"><div class="tooltip-inner"><span>' + Math.floor(curValue/10) + '</span><span class="last">años</span></div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';

  $('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);

}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#gs1").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 30,
    max: 80,
    value: initialValue,
    create: sliderTooltip,
    slide: sliderTooltip,
    animate: true
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.slider .plazo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Heavy';
  color: #007BC6;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.tooltip-slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1020;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  visibility: visible;
  margin-top: -2px;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.tooltip-slider .tooltip-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0%, 30%);
  transform-origin: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #4A4A4A;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.tooltip-inner span {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Medium';
  font-size: 20px;
}

.tooltip-inner span.last {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.slider-anyos {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-anyos .anyos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Medium';
}

.slider-anyos .anyos.last {
  left: inherit;
  right: 0;
}

.ui-slider {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 560px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
  background: #ED6B51;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a79f;
  border-right: 1px solid #a8a79f;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ui-slider-range {
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.ui-slider-range-min {
  background-color: #007BC6;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
  background: #007BC6 !important;
  border: 5px solid #fff !important;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  height: 20px !important;
  width: 20px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  top: -7px !important;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery + jquery-ui -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="slider">
  <div class="plazo">Plazo</div>
  <div class="slider-anyos">
    <div class="slider" id="gs1"></div>
    <div class="anyos first">3</div>
    <div class="anyos last">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[O quizá interese mas hacer un Math.round](https://jsfiddle.net/43tpdr6L/2/):

```js
var initialValue = 4;
var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {
  var curValue = ui.value || initialValue;
  var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip-slider"><div class="tooltip-inner"><span>' + Math.round(curValue/10) + '</span><span class="last">años</span></div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';

  $('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);

}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#gs1").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 30,
    max: 80,
    value: initialValue,
    create: sliderTooltip,
    slide: sliderTooltip,
    animate: true
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.slider .plazo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Heavy';
  color: #007BC6;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.tooltip-slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1020;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  visibility: visible;
  margin-top: -2px;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.tooltip-slider .tooltip-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0%, 30%);
  transform-origin: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #4A4A4A;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.tooltip-inner span {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Medium';
  font-size: 20px;
}

.tooltip-inner span.last {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.slider-anyos {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-anyos .anyos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Avenir-Medium';
}

.slider-anyos .anyos.last {
  left: inherit;
  right: 0;
}

.ui-slider {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 560px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
  background: #ED6B51;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a79f;
  border-right: 1px solid #a8a79f;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ui-slider-range {
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.ui-slider-range-min {
  background-color: #007BC6;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
  background: #007BC6 !important;
  border: 5px solid #fff !important;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  height: 20px !important;
  width: 20px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  top: -7px !important;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery + jquery-ui -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="slider">
  <div class="plazo">Plazo</div>
  <div class="slider-anyos">
    <div class="slider" id="gs1"></div>
    <div class="anyos first">3</div>
    <div class="anyos last">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, ¡por el momento puede servir esta opción!

Comment: De nada! Te lo acabo de editar.

Comment: Otra idea que se me ocurre, mas "limpia" pero mas compleja es mirar si con alguna animacion css3 puedes conseguir que entre step y step se mueva "lento"

Comment: Soteck, me mola mucho tu respuesta. No se si hay algo màs *correcto* pero sin duda este tipo de soluciones son las que me gustan